# java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset

Tags: java

```
add = new JButton("Add",new ImageIcon("D:/Android/Assignment/Images/bookAdd.png"));
            add.setToolTipText("Click Add to Store in Database"); // for toast 
    add.setBackground(new Color(233,214,199));
    add.setForeground(new Color(207,108,40));
    add.setFont(b);
            add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
                {
                String subject=tf2.getText();
                String title=tf3.getText();
                String author=tf4.getText();
                                    int total_books=Integer.parseInt(tf5.getText());


                    try
            {
                                    DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());                   

                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","oracle");
                                   System.out.println("11");
                                    String sql="SELECT * from ADD_BOOKS WHERE (SUBJECT=?) AND (BOOK_TITLE=?)AND (BOOK_AUTHOR=?)";
                                 // String sql="SELECT * from ADD_BOOKS VALUES(?,?,?)";

                                   PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
                                   // Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                                        System.out.println("12");
                                   pst.setString(1, subject);
                                   System.out.println("13");
                                   pst.setString(2, title);
                                   System.out.println("14");
                                   pst.setString(3, author);
                                   System.out.println("15");
                                    ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
                                    System.out.println("16");
                                 //    if (rs! = null)
                                  //   {

                                    while(rs.next())
                                         System.out.println("17");
                                    {

                                        System.out.println("18");

                                        String subjj=rs.getString(1);
                                        String titlee=rs.getString(2);
                                        String authorr=rs.getString(3);
                                     int totalBooks=Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(4));

                                   System.out.println("19");
                                    if((subject.equals(subjj)) && (title.equals(titlee)) && (author.equals(authorr)))
                                   {
                                       System.out.println("20");
                                       totalBooks=totalBooks+total_books;


                                        String updateTableSQL = "UPDATE ADD_BOOKS SET TOTAL_BOOKS = TOTAL_BOOKS+totalBooks";
                            //  + " WHERE SUBJECT = ?";
                                     PreparedStatement pstup=con.prepareStatement(updateTableSQL);            
                             //    pstup=con.prepareStatement(updateTableSQL);
                                    pstup.setInt(4, totalBooks);
                                     pstup.executeUpdate();

                                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Successfully Updated");

                                               }
                                       else
                                       {
                                        try
                                        {


                                            DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());


                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

                Connection con1=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","oracle");

                                  PreparedStatement prep1 = con1.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ADD_BOOKS VALUES(?,?, ?, ?)");

                                    prep1.setString(1, subject);

                                    prep1.setString(2, title);

                                    prep1.setString(3,author);
                                    prep1.setInt(4,total_books);

                                    prep1.executeUpdate();



                                    String nextRowId = Integer.toString(dm.getRowCount());
                                     dm.addRow(new Object[] { 
                                         nextRowId, 

                                            tf2.getText(), 
                                            tf3.getText(),
                                            tf4.getText(),
                                            tf5.getText()
                                     });

                                      tf2.setText("");
                                      tf3.setText("");
                                      tf4.setText("");
                                      tf5.setText("");
                                     System.out.println("Data Stored Into JTable Successfully");

                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data is successfully inserted into database");
                                     }
                                       catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error in submitting data");
                    }
                                       }
                                   }}
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error in submitting data");
                    }
                }});
```

Comment: Post your error stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion - always use curly braces even if you have only one line of code. In your case you didn't do this then you added System.out which was executed in the while loop and then you tried to get data when it was already retrieved.

Do like this:

```
while (rs.next()) {
                        System.out.println("17");

                        System.out.println("18");
                  //...
}
```